# Can not use value in a list column in r

Tags: r, dplyr, model, tidyverse

I am trying to make many models using list-columns but failed.

```
df <- tibble(id = 1:5, df = 1:5) %>% 
  nest(data = df)
```

Only one variable named `df` in `data`. I want to extract the value of `df` from `data`, and put it to the second argument of `ns()` function. I tried 3 ways but all failed.

```
# way 1: use df as second argument in ns()
df %>% 
    mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ ns(disp, df), data = mtcars)))
# way 2: use .  as second argument in ns()
df %>% 
    mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ ns(disp, .), data = mtcars))))
# way 3: use .x as second argument in ns()
df %>%  
    mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ ns(disp, .x), data = mtcars))))
```

How can I revise the code?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take `df` out from `.` or `.x` :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ splines::ns(disp, .x$df), data = mtcars)))

#    id   data             model 
#  <int> <list>           <list>
#1     1 <tibble [1 × 1]> <lm>  
#2     2 <tibble [1 × 1]> <lm>  
#3     3 <tibble [1 × 1]> <lm>  
#4     4 <tibble [1 × 1]> <lm>  
#5     5 <tibble [1 × 1]> <lm>
```